# Looking for function 'a -> 'b -> 'a * 'b

Tags: f#

Is there a built-in "make pair" function or operator? I know this is trivial, but it would ease function composition in some cases.

Basically, just

```
let makePair a b = a, b
```

Can I also suggest [Foogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/)?

Comment: +1 for Foogle. Hoogle had some sort of extensibility model, but I'm not quite sure if that would work for F# too (we have to deal with all those .NET types too)

Comment: Nobody wants foogle because it sounds too similar to Google's Froogle flop.

Comment: There is Fing: https://github.com/sandersn/fing but it isn't as strong as Hoogle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think there is a function like that in the F# library (and you also cannot treat `,` as an operator, which is allowed in Haskell).

F# lacks many other functions that are often used in function composition (or point-free style) including `flip : ('a -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a` and `curry : ('a * 'b -> c) -> 'a -> 'b - 'c`). Frankly, I think that this is a good thing because it discourages people from writing code that is hard to read.

Of course, there are many cases where using some function like this would give readable code, but it is really difficult to find the right ballance.

Comment: I knew `,` is a syntactic form, but I thought there might be something similar in the bowels of the Core libs.

Comment: @Daniel Yeah :-). We can't win in _that_ battle!

Answer (score 0):

[FSharpx](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx) aims to fill some of those gaps (whenever possible). It has [flip, curry](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/blob/master/src/FSharpx/Prelude.fs) and [tuple constructors](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/blob/master/src/FSharpx/Collections.fs#L11) (among many other things).

If you're really interested in building Hoogle for F# you could [work with Neil Mitchell](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2011/03/hoogle-for-your-language-ie-f-scala-ml.html) (creator of Hoogle) to implement it.